# Can nginx block ~20000 ips?

Tags: nginx, ip, block

Can nginx block ~20.000 ips?

And should i block ips (https://lists.blocklist.de/lists/all.txt) with nginx?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, you could block those IPs by using the `deny` config option in nginx: e.g., with the file `/etc/nginx/denyip.conf`

```
deny 1.1.1.1;
deny 2.2.2.0/24;
deny 3.3.3.3;
```

And then in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in your HTTP block

```
include denyip.conf;
```

However, you shouldn't really be blocking IP addresses with Nginx. It is much better to block them with your firewall, so they can't connect to your server at all, instead of being able to connect to everything but Nginx.

Comment: tx, makes sense now you mention it. So you would block them at the Ubuntu ufw level for instance or at the router level?